# Reading in a .cat file that is a talbe into Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read in numerous ".cat" (catalog) files into panda tables so I can manipulate the data easier. I am not familiar with ".cat" files, but in this case each file looks like a text file table with columns and data. I tried using pd.read_csv(filename) since I figured it was space separated, not comma separated but similiar.

```py
clustname = ["SpARCS-0035", "SpARCS-0219", "SpARCS-0335", "SpARCS-1034", "SpARCS-1051", "SpARCS-1616",\
             "SpARCS-1634", "SpARCS-1638", "SPTCL-0205", "SPTCL-0546", "SPTCL-2106"]
for iclust in range(len(clustname)):
    rfcolpath = restframe + 'RESTFRAME_MASTER_' + clustname[iclust] + '_indivredshifts.cat'

    rfcol_table[iclust] = pd.read_csv(rfcolpath[iclust], engine='python')
    
    rfcol_table.head()
```

And I got "ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Calling read(nbytes) on source failed. Try engine='python'." as an error. So I tried adding in "engine = 'python'" to the read_csv command and got this error: "IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/'". I don't know what this means or how to fix it, how should I read in each individual file? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import subprocess
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
task = subprocess.Popen(["cat file.txt"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in task.stdout:
    df=pd.concat([df, line])
task.wait()
```

Comment: I got an error code: "OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/home/caelan/GOGREEN_TEMP/DR1/PHOTOMETRY/RESTFRAME_COLOURS/RESTFRAME_MASTER_SpARCS-0035_indivredshifts.cat'"

Comment: this error may also happen when target of Popen is not executable.